# Json_encode returning undefined value

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm having trouble while using json encode from php, I always get undefined.

php:

```
<?php
     header('Content-Type: application/json');

     $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "", "canchas");

     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
     }

     $consulta = "SELECT nombre FROM empresa";
     $resultado = mysqli_query($link, "$consulta"); 

     $data = array();
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
        $data[] = $row;
    } 
    mysqli_close($link);

    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("listaCanchas.php", function(data) {
    alert(data.nombre);
});
```

It does work if I do this in my php file:

```
$data['nombre'] = "Pepe";
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: undefined "what" *exactly?*

Comment: `$data` is an array, so `data.nombre` would not be defined. Try `data[0].nombre`

Comment: @Fred-ii- the alert message says "undefined".

Comment: @ExplosionPills tried that and get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined"

Comment: @Ivan Can you please print_r($data) right before the json_encode? Just to be sure that variable $data holds data. EDIT : Also, are you sure you are not getting any other errors? Your first IF statement seems wrong.

Comment: Or try `console.log(data)` and see what's in `data`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos print_r: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Patronato ) [1] => Array ( [0] => El Paseo ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Azia ) ) [["Patronato"],["El Paseo"],["Azia"]] . I used the other code (connection and that IF and it has always worked).

Comment: @empiric console.log(data) shows this: Array[3]
0:Array[1]
0:"Patronato"
length:1
__proto__:Array[0]
1:Array[1]
0:"El Paseo"
length:1
__proto__:Array[0]
1__proto__:Array[0]
length:3
__proto__:
Array[0]

Comment: @Ivan How do you call the $.getJSON function?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos function capturarCanchas(){
  $.getJSON....
} I call this function from another function when a button is pressed.

Comment: @Ivan Can't see a 'nombre' inside your print_r() .

Comment: Can you try using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills that worked perfectly :)

Comment: Changed code layout and changed html -> jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mysqli_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) returns the result as an enumerated array, i.e. each property will be a number. Instead, you want an associative array with named properties.

You can use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to do this instead. This will give you an array of objects in JSON, so you can update to `console.log(data[0].nombre)` to test it out. `data` will be an array of objects you can iterate over in JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked by changing this:

```
 $data = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

to this:

```
$data = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
    $data['nombre'][$i] = $row[0];
    $i++;
}
```